# How to use ffmpeg concat protocol with too many files?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I use ffmpeg Concat protocol with so many files, that I cannot run it through cmd because  of command-line string limitation?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. I have written them wish-form.